# How to use autocorrect in Pandas column of sentences

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, autocorrect

I have a column of sentences, which i am splitting like so

```
df['ColTest'] = df['ColTest'].str.lower().str.split()
```

What i am trying to do is loop through each word in each sentence and apply the autocorrect.spell()

```
for i in df['ColTest']:
for j in i:
    df['ColTest'][i][j].replace(at.spell(j))
```

This is throwing up an error

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Autospell [autospell](https://github.com/phatpiglet/autocorrect/)

DataFrame looks like

```
ColTest
This is some test string
that might contain a finger
but this string might contain a toe
and this hass a spel error
```

There are no numbers in my column...any ideas please?

Comment: Could you please share few lines of the dataframe df ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [autocorrect library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autocorrect/0.2.0), you need to iterate through the rows of the dataframe then iterate through the words within a given row to apply the `spell` method. Here's a working example:

```
from autocorrect import spell 
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(["and this hass a spel error"], columns=["colTest"])
df.colTest.apply(lambda x: " ".join([spell(i) for i in x.split()]))
```

Also as suggested by @jpp in the comment below, we can avoid using `lambda`as follows:

```
df["colTest"] = [' '.join([spell(i) for i in x.split()]) for x in df['colTest']]
```

---

Here's how the input looks like:

```
                      colTest
0  and this hass a spel error
```

---

Output:

```
0    and this has a spell error
Name: colTest, dtype: object
```

Comment: Alternatively, avoid `lambda` with something like: `df['colTest'] = [' '.join([spell(i) for i in x.split()]) for x in df['colTest']]`

Comment: @jpp I added your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Good post! Just a note that autocorrect.spell is now deprecated.  But the same works with autocorrect.Speller. `from autocorrect import Speller`, 'spell = Speller(lang='en')` and the rest works as-is.